# Hiding folder and drive in windows

Tags: windows, operating-system

I got some tutorial for hiding folders and drive in system.

1) command

```
attrib +h +s <folder_name>
```

it will hide the folder and for visiblilty

```
attrib -h -s <folder_name>
```

2) hide drive
command propmt

```
$diskpart
$list volumn
$select volumn <volumn num>
$remove letter <volumn letter>
```

this will hide volumn from my computer

what is actully happend in system?

Please give your suggessions

Comment: File attributes such as the hidden and system attributes are metadata stored in the file system. Windows [`FindFirstFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364419) lists hidden and system files like any other. Whether or not they get displayed is up to the shell. The default behavior of Explorer and cmd's `dir` is to filter out these files. You can configure Explorer to show hidden and system files, and `dir` has the options `/ah` and `/as`.

Comment: Volumes are given a long GUID name of the form `Volume{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}` that you can see in the output of the `mountvol` command. To interact with a volume normally via the shell it needs to be mounted as a DOS drive or to a directory of another drive. OTOH, a program using the Windows API can use the long GUID name instead, if necessary.